# How to display a string from angularjs 1.4 on a asp.net mvc popup window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a simple message using angularjs 1.4 on a keno UI popup window in asp.net mvc.  The following is my MVC view and javascript

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "MyDocument";

}

 <div  ng-app="MyTech">
 <div id="window"  ng-controller="MyDocumentController">

    {{Message}}


</div>
</div>



(function () {
"use strict";

var app = angular.module('MyTech', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('MyDocumentController', function ($scope) {              $scope.Message = "Hello";
  });
}());
```

But only {{Message}} is displayed and doesn't resolve to "Hello"

Comment: You are missing an ng-controller/ng-app declaration which is probably your issue.

Comment: Actually I have both. I have reformatted my question. Now they show them.

Comment: Did you include the JavaScript files to run angular?

Comment: Yes, I have added it as part of the bundle

Comment: OK, but did you reference that bundle in your code?  It's not in your questino.

Comment: Will the problem be that the page is a popup window. It is a kendo popup window which displays the asp.net mvc view. I have included the cdn for the angularjs 1.4.2 and the module and controller containing js files, still doesn't work!

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/app/todolist/app.js"></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102850/discussion-between-drifter-and-casey).